# Stop the auto resize of the uiwebview web content when focus on input field

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with a html form in it. The problem is that when I tap on the input field, the UIWebView automatically zoom in to the area close to the input field with the keyboard shows up. However, when the input is done and the keyboard is hidden, the html content remains zoom in. 
Is there a way to stop this behavior or programmatically resize the content back to the original view? (it is already registered with the keyboard hide event)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the font-size CSS property of the input to 16px or use a  "viewport" meta tag with the user-scaling property (which disables user zooming)  set to no:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

if that doesn't cut it add "initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" which will prevent all zooming:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: @evanwong did this answer not resolve your question, or at least help?

Comment: @evanwong, if it did answer please mark at as the correct answer. Thanks :)